# What did David Gilmour exactly say in this video about his Black Strat?

Tags: history, pink-floyd

In this [video](https://youtu.be/TVjFJFEQ_OU?t=27), David Gilmour talks about his Black Strat.

What does it say at the beginning of the video?
Did he said "I got it I believed (or lived?) in 1970s whenever (or wherever) realizing (or other words) you can't go see"?

Answer (score 4):

The first two sentences are quite clear to me:

> I got it from Many's, I believe in 1970. Wherever I was in New York, I'd go see Henry and Many's.

He is talking about where he bought his famous [Black Strat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Strat), which he bought at the now closed [Manny's Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manny's_Music) in New York.

Comment: Also, he's most likely talking about Henry Goldrich - the owner of Manny's